# Find the rate at which y is changing.

Tags: calculus

Two distances, $x$ and $y$, from a fixed point are related by the expression

$3x^2=9y+8$.

If distance $x$ is increasing at a rate of $18$ m/s. Find the rate at which $y$ is changing.

Comment: Have you heard about implicit differentiation?

Comment: no, ill google it now

Comment: It basically says that you're allowed to differentiate the whole equality with respect to $x$, where then $y\mapsto y'$ and remembering that you're given $x' = 18$. Then you can solve for $y'$ and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Given: $$y = \frac{1}{3}x^2 - \frac{8}{9}$$ $$\frac{dx}{dt} = 18.$$

Now note:
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}$$

Can you solve it from here?

Comment: This gives an answer in terms of $x$.  I don't believe there is enough information to solve it without the answer depending on $x$.

Comment: i got 12x? is that correct?

Comment: Well one can say $x = x_0 + 18t$, but indeed, there isn't enough information to state what this $x_0$ needs to be.

Comment: @Happy Yes! Do you know anything about $y$ and $x$ for $t = 0$?

Comment: no I don't sorry

Answer (score 1):

Differntate w.r.t time $t$

$$ 6 x \dot x = 9  \dot y $$

Plug in $ x,y, \dot x $  and finding

$$ \dot y = 2 x \dot x /3 = 12 \,x $$

is not possible for want of $x$ value.